get crd events after kubectl apply
in my deployment i use kubectl apply to create or configure a couple of kubernetes resources. afterward i would like to capture the events of those crds for the deployment process.
so far i use this
resources=$(kubectl apply -f deployment/uat/ -n nifi-cluster -o name)
echo "Resources applied: $resources"

resource_names=$(echo "$resources" | awk -F'/' '{print $2}')

for resource_name in $resource_names; do
  echo "Events for $resource_name"
  kubectl get events -n nifi-cluster --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | grep -E "$resource_name"
done

my main problem is with this line resource_names=$(echo "$resources" | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'). The problem is that kubectl apply returns the resource name it found like this externalsecret.external-secrets.io/example-external-secret. Meanwhile kubectl get events is identifying the same resource as externalsecret/external-secret-nifi-sap-xtract-uat. so without this .external-secrets.io.
Is there a way to either get the events with the full identification or get the apply response without the full id. The way i do it now does not seem very robust.

Can you use a richer language than the Bourne shell for this?  Then you won't be tied to this sort of string manipulation (API objects' group, version, and kind are typically split out) and you won't be trying to work with kubectl's specific output format.

kubectl get events only for a pod suggests you can kubectl get event --field-selector involvedObject.name=example-external-secret, and similarly filter by the apiVersion and kind, without using grep.  Does that approach work for you?
